# Stop after second space - regular expression doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make a program to recognize a pattern from the .txt file. I want it to remember ("word" space "word"), and then when it hits another space it stops.

I have looked up a lot of examples for the pattern, but none of them seem to work.

Here is the code I have:

```
private void parsing(String line){
    String pattern;
    pattern = "(.*[^\\s]+)"; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    boolean b = m.matches();
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Here is an output:

```
hsad vova 13/12/1995 16/05/2005 01/09/2017 17/03/2018
hsad vova 13/12/1995 16/05/2005 01/09/2017 17/03/2018
```

P.S. The program reads this information from the .txt file using BufferedReader.

Here is a full code if it's needed:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class insuranceSupport {
   InputStreamReader streamReader =  new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/database.txt"));
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
   String thisLine;
      public void getLine(){
           ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
           try {
                while ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    list.add(thisLine);
                    System.out.println(thisLine);
                    parsing(thisLine);
            }
      }    catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }

}
    private void parsing(String line){
        String pattern;
        pattern = "(.*[^\\s]+)"; 
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
}

}
```

And the main:

```
public class insuranceMain {
public static void main(String args[]){
    insuranceSupport inc = new insuranceSupport();
    inc.getLine();

}
```

}

Sorry for so much information. I have been researching this for a long time and could not find a solution; just wanted to make sure it's possible for others to resolve this problem.

Thanks for your effort and time!

Comment: What content in your `database.txt` and what output you want?

Comment: "hsad vova 13/12/1995 16/05/2005 01/09/2017 17/03/2018" is a content of the file database.txt (it's just one line).  I want to write a pattern that will save only "hsad vova" @alijandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regular expression to extract the result

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+).*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("hsad vova 13/12/1995 16/05/2005 01/09/2017 17/03/2018");
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

A more simple way to use split

```
    String[] strings = "hsad vova 13/12/1995 16/05/2005 01/09/2017 17/03/2018".split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(strings[0]);
    System.out.println(strings[1]);
```

Comment: I wanted to put "hsad" and "vova" together as the one string("hsad vova"), not separately like you did it. But I have played with the parentheses a little, and I got "hsad vova" as the one string. Thanks, you helped me a lot.